# PHP regex - count number of exclamation marks before and after a word

Tags: php, regex

I need help to refine a regex, in PHP, intended to count the number of exclamation marks that appear before and after a word. Words, in this situation, can include any character except a space (even exclamation marks), as follows (I am showing the expected "before, after" counts):

```
!!!!Hi!! => 4, 2
!!!!Hi  => 4, 0
!Hi!!!  => 1, 3
!easdf.kjaf!!  => 1, 2
!hjdfa!sdfk!jaf!!  => 1, 2
!,!!!!!fdgsdfg!!sdgj => 1, 0
!!!,!ksfgfdg!jkft!!!  => 3, 3
```

How to code the regex so that, for the before, it stops looking for consecutive exclamation marks when some non-exclamation mark is reached, and start counting for the after when there are only exclamation marks remaining?

The tricky part, is when punctuation characters appear within the word. These should be ignored, these are considered as part of the word.

Here is where I am at:

```
 preg_match_all('/(!*)\b(\S+)\b(!*)/', $w, $m);
```

$w is the word (as shown above), $m is matching array

As an example, "!!Hi!" would result in $m equal to

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!Hi!
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hi
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => !
        )
)
```

That is correct and what I am looking for. However, things get thrown off when a punctuation character starts or ends the word , the regex anchor "\b" does not recognize that as part of the word (as it is defined in this exercise). Here is an example of a failure to parse the word "!!!!!!!!xd.sfgdx!!!,!!"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!!!!!!xd.sfgdx!!!
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!!!!!!
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => xd.sfgdx
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!
        )
)
```

Help, please.

Comment: Start is `^`, end is `$`

Comment: Why not just create a list of forbidden characters and do a str_replace to clean things up before running the fancy regex?

Answer (score 3):

You just need anchors (`^` for beginning and `$` for end) and basically anything in the middle. With anchors, a middle `!` won't match if it is not on either ends. This might be a first attempt;

```
/^(!*).*(!*)$/
```

The problem with the anything in the middle here (`.*`) is that it is greedy, and will take precedence over the final group `(!*)`. The anything in the middle would match all to the end and the group just nothing. Simple to fix though, just make the middle un-greedy:

```
/^(!*).*?(!*)$/
```

Now it will match any `!` on the beginning, as much as possible, then anything in the middle step by step until the next condition matches (`!` at the end).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick non-regex solution, just because:

```
$test = ['!!!!Hi!!',
         '!!!!Hi',
         '!Hi!!!',
         '!easdf.kjaf!!',
         '!hjdfa!sdfk!jaf!!',
         '!,!!!!!fdgsdfg!!sdgj',
         '!!!,!ksfgfdg!jkft!!!'];

foreach($test as $str) {
    $count = $rcount = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i] == '!') {
            $count += 1;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    for ($i = strlen($str) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if ($str[$i] == '!') {
            $rcount += 1;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    echo $str . ': ' . $count . ', ' . $rcount . '<br />';
}
```

**Output:**

```
!!!!Hi!!: 4, 2
!!!!Hi: 4, 0
!Hi!!!: 1, 3
!easdf.kjaf!!: 1, 2
!hjdfa!sdfk!jaf!!: 1, 2
!,!!!!!fdgsdfg!!sdgj: 1, 0
!!!,!ksfgfdg!jkft!!!: 3, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had been looking for a purely Regex solution but when I became overwhelmed I adopted something along the lines of what you had done for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp:

```
preg_match_all('/^(!*)[^!]{1}.*[^!]{1}(!*)/', $w, $m);
```

For you examples outputs are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!!Hi!!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!!
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!,!ksfgfdg!jkft!!,!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!!
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => !
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That was pretty much working as hoped... though it breaks if the string is either all "!!!!!!!!!!!!" or if there is only one character within a bunch of exclamation marks in the string "...!!!!!!N!!!!!!!!...."